# How to handle click on button without ID but with value?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

The third-party library provides web SDK with a button without ID but with value?
So, I could not add the ID to it.

How to handle click (like `getElementbyId`) and add the listener to it?

```
<input value="Some Value">
```

Comment: With some of the surrounding html it would be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use querySelector for that to get the input with a specific value, like that

```
document.querySelector('input[value="Some Value"]');
```

Comment: But in order to select element you need to have at least something, if you only know that it is an input or a button, you can't select it. Only if it's the only button or input on the page, you could do ```document.querySelector('input');```. You can also try digging into it from parent nodes.